# Adaptive Subdivision ignores Auto Smooth angle

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm using the experimental feature set in cycles. I've added a subdivision surface modifier to my geo. When I check "adaptive subdivision", the "simple" subdivision algorithm smoothes the edges of my geometry. This doesn't seem right... does anyone know how to stop this? I don't remember this happening in the past. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Auto Smooth and Adaptive Subdivision don't appear to work together. It's like Adaptive Subdivision ignores the Auto Smooth angle and just shades it smooth. Changing the auto smooth angle has no effect. Since adaptive subdivision is still an experimental feature set, I'm guessing this is a bug? If I'm wrong please help.

I'm using Blender version 2.90.1.
[image]

Comment: You can still switch between smooth and flat shading in the Object menu.

Comment: The object is shaded flat, it's only when I toggle the simple subdivision algorithm with adaptive subdivision checked that it renders smooth for some reason.